# XSD: how to implement a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: xml, xsd, relationship

Let's say I have a many-to-many relationship between customers and retailers. One Customer can have multiple retailers and one retailer can have multiple customers.

So, in XSD, I'd write something like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://mynamespace" 
            targetNamespace="http://mynamespace" 
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="shop">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="retailer" />
        <xs:element ref="customer" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="retailer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="customer" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="customer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="retailer" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem here is when I want to insert a `retailer R1`, then I'd associate a `customer C1` to him, which then gets `retailer R1` associated again (`R1 -> C1 -> R1`) - resulting in a fine recursive loop.

So how should one go about those cases?

#### EDIT

So what I have in mind is something similar to how RDBMs handle n-m-relations. I have two tables (`customer` and `retailer`) and a third table `customer_retailer`, which only contains the primary keys of the other two tables as unique foreign key-pairs.

In XSD, what I can imagine is that I let users create retailers and customers independently from another, and inside each element-instance reference only a key to the specific element. That is, I do not do this:

```
<retailer>
  <customer>
    <retailer>
      ...
    </retailer>
  </customer>
</retailer>
```

But this:

```
<retailer id="r1">
  <customer ref_id="c1" />
  <customer ref_id="c2" />
</retailer>
<customer id="c1">
  <retailer ref_id="r1" />
  <retailer ref_id="r2" />
</customer>
...
```

Comment: Where are you going to use this XSD to represent that relationship? What language, framework? Please edit your question and add the corresponding tags.

Comment: I do not understand your question(s). You mean what other programming language/environment I'm using? I don't use anything, this is a theoretical question about xml-schema declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with XSD. You can certainly hold both directions of the relationship in your XML document if you want (it's up to you), but if you do, then it's your responsibility when you write code to update the structure to keep the two directions of the relationship in sync, and to avoid infinite loops. That's hardly a difficult problem, but the details depend entirely on how you are implementing your update logic.

Comment: Yes, this problem persists for databases in general, however the bit related to XSD is this: In RDBMs I'd usually use a third table that has both primary keys as foreign keys, comprising together the pkey for the helper table. Now in XSD, I don't see how I can do that. From what I understand, the 'russian doll design' of XSD kind of prevents such representations. I mean, I know I am missing something here, but from my perspective, my question is all about XSD design, nothing else.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with your schema design. The problem you report is in creating an instance document without your program going into an infinite loop, and that's a problem with your program design, not your schema design.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can agree with you. In fact, I doubt it is possible to create a valid instance from the schema, because this schema _requires_ the instance to have this recursive loop. Simply because there is no `minOccurs="0"` in the elements. Either way, something like this ought to be handled by the ruleset, not the implementation. Please see my updated question to what I have in mind.

Comment: You would have a problem creating an instance if you were incrementally adding information and the information had to be schema-valid after each incremental addition. But that's not usually the way XML gets created. This is why I asked you how you were implementing your update logic, a question you havne't answered.

Comment: Ah! Well I am learning xml/xsd and figuring this out for an assignment. So my concern is that however I update the xml, it always has to be schema-valid. But reading your replies, it seems to me that schemas are usually treated as 'suggestions' rather than enforcements in the real world ;)

Comment: No, you still haven't grasped it. A schema is a like a certificate you give to someone who is a fully qualified teacher. They don't have to have the certificate at every stage of their training.